# I can't get live data with c#

Tags: c#

I want to pull live data with htmlagilitypack. I need to get cryptocurrency prices instantly. I'm doing a 5 second refresh with the timer in the project but always the first value comes. For example, dolar is now 8,65try but after 15 seconds it's 8,70try. The data I get is always 8,65try the first value.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri url = new Uri("https://www.bloomberght.com/borsa");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    string html = client.DownloadString(url);
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(html);
    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='dolar']/span[@class='data-info']/small[@data-type='son_fiyat']");

    foreach (var item in nodes)
    {
        string link = item.Attributes["class"].Value;
        label1.Text = item.InnerText;
        listBox1.Items.Add(item.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technical issues aside, I suspect you are violating the ToS of this site and might face counter measures if your scraping is detected. Imho if you want real time data services, you should use the paid service API.

Answer (score 4):

You may be hitting cache.

Try to specify `BypassCache` level for your request:

```
client.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
```